# How to combine JSON objects with the same key, using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following snippet exported as JSON:

```json
{
  "daisy": {
    "dev": {
      "app_url": "example.com",
      "owner": "bob",
      "createat": "2022-06-17T15:31:58Z",
    }
  }
}
{
  "daisy": {
    "dev": {
      "appname": "daisy",
      "flavor": [
        "nodejs"
      ],
      "file": "manifests/daisy.yml"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to combine these objects into something like this:

```json
{
  "daisy": {
    "dev": {
      "app_url": "example.com",
      "owner": "bob",
      "createat": "2022-06-17T15:31:58Z",
      "appname": "daisy",
      "flavor": [
        "nodejs"
      ],
      "file": "manifests/daisy.yml"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this with `jq`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Multiplying two objects together will merge them. The following uses `reduce` to successively build up a new object by merging the existing objects one by one.

Two similar ways to do this:

1. Using `-n` and `inputs` with `reduce`:

   ```bash
   jq -n 'reduce inputs as $item ({}; . *= $item)' file
   ```

   This uses the `inputs` function, which returns the incoming objects one by one.  This is combined with `-n` (`--null-input`) to disable the ordinary reading of inputs.
2. Using `-s` and `.[]` with `reduce`:

   ```bash
   jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . *= $item)' file
   ```

   This reads the original data with `-s` (`--slurp`) into an array, and `reduce` is used to iterate over that array. Note that this is severely memory-inefficient and slow if the input is huge.

The result, given your data (and correcting it by removing a comma on the `createat` line):

```json
{
  "daisy": {
    "dev": {
      "app_url": "example.com",
      "owner": "bob",
      "createat": "2022-06-17T15:31:58Z",
      "appname": "daisy",
      "flavor": [
        "nodejs"
      ],
      "file": "manifests/daisy.yml"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if two or more objects share the same key and if that key refers to a *scalar* or *array*, then the later objects in the input will overwrite the value.